Python Flask Sqlite is not creating a column in a specific line or name
This is just mind blowing
I am trying to use in-memory table for small data that can be got easily but I dont want to send request all the time, so I save it in in-memory sqlite table
here is my init.py file:
from flask import Flask
from .models import db
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler  # Corrected import

class Config:
    SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True
    # SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///..//db.sqlite3'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() # Create the database tables - IMPORTANT
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()  # Corrected class name
    scheduler.start()
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    return app

I wrote db.sqlite3 to be able to see it in vs-code, but it works the same in in-memory table
And here is my table:
class Holidays(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Holidays'
    data_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # date format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
    date = db.Column(db.String)
    
    
    test = db.Column(db.String)
    test2 = db.Column(db.Float)
    test3 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # sholday = db.Column(db.Integer) 
    # sholday = db.Column(db.Integer)
    test4 = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    isholday = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sholday = db.Column(db.Integer)
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, holiday):
        db.session.add(holiday)
        db.session.commit()
    @classmethod
    def add_all(cls, holidays):
        db.session.add_all(holidays)
        db.session.commit()
    @classmethod
    def sholday(cls, date):
        holiday = Holidays.query.filter(Holidays.date == date).first()
        if holiday:
            return holiday.sholday
        return False
    @classmethod
    def does_date_exist(cls, date):
        return Holidays.query.filter(Holidays.date == date).first() is not None

now here, it creates every column except sholday, I initially made its name is_holiday but it wasn't creating also with that name. I copied pasted this line to somewhere else, I changed the name, it is not creating that column.

The problem is, there is a function definition with the same name.
Even though there is no error in runtime or during development, this problem is related to having a function with same name.
sholday = db.Column(db.Integer)
def sholday(cls, date):
    holiday = Holidays.query.filter(Holidays.date == date).first()

Rename the function to something else to get rid of the error
